# How to clear window using xcb

Tags: c, xorg, xcb

I want to create a simple app with xcb that's just a screen with one line. Background being black and foreground white. I know how to draw a line onto a created window, but I haven't found any documentation on how to clear the screen. I should also note that I'm using a compositor(picom to be more specific) so an undefined background looks strange, using a different GC and just filling the whole screen is a solution, but I think there is a better way.

Comment: Try xcb_clear_area, you need a defined background for this (not "none"). If you don't want that, try xcb_poly_fill_rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for.